# RocksDB merge operands versus input/output values

Tags: c++, merge, rocksdb

RocksDB supports row update operations through [the `MergeOperator` interface](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Merge-Operator). I am trying to understand better
how the `AssociativeMergeOperator` works.

The merge implementation of the associative merge operator is expected to provide the following method:

```
      // Gives the client a way to express the read -> modify -> write semantics
      // key:           (IN) The key that's associated with this merge operation.
      // existing_value:(IN) null indicates the key does not exist before this op
      // value:         (IN) the value to update/merge the existing_value with
      // new_value:    (OUT) Client is responsible for filling the merge result here
      // logger:        (IN) Client could use this to log errors during merge.
      //
      // Return true on success. Return false failure / error / corruption.
      virtual bool Merge(const Slice& key,
                         const Slice* existing_value,
                         const Slice& value,
                         std::string* new_value,
                         Logger* logger) const = 0;
```

If one compares this with the interface of the full `MergeOperator::FullMerge` method, one sees that method instead receives a collection of **operands**. In fact the associative merge operator also seems to be receiving operands, it is just the argument called `value`, which is literally the "value" argument slice passed to `DB::Merge(WriteOptions&, ColumnFamilyHandle*, const Slice& key, const Slice& value_operand)`. Both `existing_value` and `new_value` are actual input and output values, and **as far as I can understand**, they can never represent operands.

Suppose the merge operation supports just adding or removing ids from a list. In this case operands are semantically things like:

```
previous value: []
operand: "append(id=3)"
new value:      [3]

previous value: [3]
operand: "append(id=7)"
new value:      [3, 7]

previous value: [3, 7]
operand: "remove(id=3)"
new value:      [7]
```

in which the corresponding merge operations are invoked like:

```
db->Merge(WriteOptions(), cf, keySlice, SliceFrom("append(id=3)"));
db->Merge(WriteOptions(), cf, keySlice, SliceFrom("append(id=7)"));
db->Merge(WriteOptions(), cf, keySlice, SliceFrom("remove(id=3)"));
```

Does this approach in any way violate the expectations of an associative merge operator? If it does, why?